# Postgres Sql query for no of records within a time stamp around 30 min

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a Postgres sql which will get me the flights within 30 min of a particular timestamp.

My SQL looks like :

"Select count(distinct(gufi)) as No_of_airplanes from lk_merged a
where (a.on_actual between ( a.on_actual -(20* interval '1 minute')) and (a.on_actual  +(40 * interval '1 minute')) )
group by a.on_actual"

Please suggest how to get those no of planes.

My table has gufi as airplane id, on_actual_timelanding.

what i have :
gufi(plane_id) , time
3432343,12:33:89
2565656,12:44:45
3242234,1:05:23

Output should look like , with a new column suggesting no_of_planes_around within 20 min before and after time stamp

Gufi(plane_id) , Time stamp , No_of planes arround
3432343        , 12:33:89, 1
2565656        , 12:44:45 ,2
3242234        ,1:05:23 ,1

Please suggest something if possible without self join.

Thanks
Love Tyagi

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be helpful

Comment: You've shown us SQL that you've tried. Can you tell us why that's not working, what it gives you, and what you'd rather it give you? Also, anything else you've tried.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: You are checking if a timestamp is in interval relative to the timestamp itself which will always be true... you should use another timestamp in the between operator.

Comment: Looks like you program in Go :-) try to use this condition: `between ( a.on_actual - interval '20 minutes' and a.on_actual  + interval '40 minutes'`. You can have boundaries in text variables and do `between ( a.on_actual - variable1::interval  and a.on_actual  + variable2::interval`

Answer (score 0):

Ii isn't possible to use COUNT(DISTINCT ...) if using COUNT() as a windowed function, if you try you get this the error "0A000: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions". So to have this count calculated with distinct, and output on each row of output, I suggest using CROSS JOIN LATERAL.

Note I wasn't certain in your small example of data that 1:05:23 = 01:05:23 or 13:05:23 so I included both.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   plane_id   INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,plane_time TIME NOT NULL
)
\\
INSERT INTO mytable(plane_id,plane_time) VALUES (3432343,TO_TIMESTAMP('12:33:89', 'HH24:MI:SS')::TIME)\\
INSERT INTO mytable(plane_id,plane_time) VALUES (2565656,TO_TIMESTAMP('12:44:45', 'HH24:MI:SS')::TIME)\\
INSERT INTO mytable(plane_id,plane_time) VALUES (3242234,TO_TIMESTAMP('01:05:23', 'HH24:MI:SS')::TIME)\\
INSERT INTO mytable(plane_id,plane_time) VALUES (3242234,TO_TIMESTAMP('13:05:23', 'HH24:MI:SS')::TIME)\\

select * 
from mytable t1
cross join lateral (
    select count(distinct plane_id) No_of_planes_around
    from mytable t2 
    where t2.plane_time between t1.plane_time - interval '20 minutes' and t1.plane_time + interval '40 minutes'
    --and t1.plane_id <> t2.plane_id
    ) cjl
\\
```

Also I wasn't sure if the count should include the plane of the current row or not so I included it, but you can exclude it by making the row "and t1.plane_id <> t2.plane_id" active in the query.